# SceneKit, iOS - make 3D particles?

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, 3d, scenekit, arkit

Ok, researching SCNParticlesystem here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticlesystem and building a 3D game in SceneKit with Swift -

I cant find anything on SO - how can I make a particle emitter w/ 3D shapes/from a .dae file? I can make a 3D particle emitter in Blender - do I need/is it possible to import this into Xcode?

How can I achieve 3D particles? Or do I just need to spawn repeatedly 3D models.